# using Python to check values in a range for large data samples

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, range

I'm trying to determine which values, in a large list of integers, falls within any of the ranges in a second DataFrame of integers. I have this working using nested loops and pandas arrays but it is incredibly slow and I can't find a more efficient way to do it.  I tried adding a break, but it does not behave as I hoped.  Here is a sample of what I have - in reality, my files have ~10k values:

```
import pandas as pd

mat = pd.DataFrame([[1849,"C", "G", "T", "T"],
[1977,"A", "G", "T", "T"],
[4013,"T", "G", "T", "T"],
[7362,"G", "G", "T", "T"],
[7570,"C", "G", "T", "T"],
[7585,"G", "G", "T", "T"],
[9304,"G", "G", "T", "T"],
[11820,"C", "G", "T", "T"],
[11879,"A", "G", "T", "T"],
[14785,"T", "G", "T", "T"],
[14861,"G", "G", "T", "T"],
[15117,"C", "G", "T", "T"],
[15890,"G", "G", "T", "T"],
[16119,"C", "G", "T", "T"],
[17654,"T", "G", "T", "T"],
[17657,"T", "G", "T", "T"],
[20039,"C", "G", "T", "T"]], columns = ["Pos","Ref", "FileA", "FileB", "FileC"])

cov = pd.DataFrame([["chrom_1", 10,100],
["chrom_1", 10, 1900],
["chrom_1", 2000, 5000],
["chrom_1", 10000, 11111],
["chrom_1", 12110, 13110],
["chrom_1", 13410, 15510],
["chrom_1", 15512, 17510],
["chrom_1", 19512, 20032]], columns = ["Chrom", "Start", "End"])

for file_name in mat.columns.values[-(len(mat.columns.values)-2):]:
    #for each column in the data frame called mat, except Pos and Ref
    row_count = 0
    try:
        # find the file with the ranges matching the column name 
        #this is just example code
#        cov = pd.read_csv(str(find_file(file_name+"*", cov_dir)[0]), sep = "\t")
        cov = cov
        # the column names of this file are Chrom Start End
        #iterate over positions in data frame and if present if file, convert to -
        for value in mat["Pos"]:
            for row in range(len(cov)):
                if value <= cov["End"][row] and value >= cov["Start"][row]:
                    #does the value fall within this range?
                    mat[file_name][row_count] = '-'
                    # mat.loc[:,(file_name, row_count)] = '-'
#                  if value > cov["End"][row]:
#                      break
            row_count += 1
    except:
        pass
        #logging.debug('No file found for: ' + file_name)

print mat
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
if np.logical_and(int(value) <= cov["End"], int(value) >= cov["Start"]).sum() > 0:
```

This was a lot faster, I assume the logical operators would do a similar job.